# Why is array_filter returning a reference?

Tags: php, array-filter

I would like to understand the difference between these two ( `$bookingRows` is an array of objects with different properties).

```
$vehicleRows = [];
foreach($bookingRows as $row) {
 if($row->GroupCode == 'F') {
   $vehicleRows[] = clone $row;
 }
}
```

and

```
$vehicleRows = array_values(
 array_filter($bookingRows, function ($row) {
   return $row->GroupCode == 'F';
 })
);
```

My problem is that if I modify something in the  `$vehicleRows` array, it reflects these changes in the origin, `$bookingRows`, as well -- which is not what I want. How can I avoid such an unwanted reference between the origin and the filtered set of items?

Comment: Objects are *always* passed by reference. In the first block you use `clone` to get a new copy of the object. The `array_filter` version does not clone anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your code use `clone`? Because otherwise it produces the same result as `array_filter()`.

`array_filter()` is not the culprit here, the PHP objects are manipulated through a handle. That handle is copied on assignments and this is what `array_filter()` does. The objects are not duplicated unless one uses `clone` to explicitly duplicate them.

The [PHP documentation page about objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) mentions this behaviour:

> PHP treats objects in the same way as references or handles, meaning that each variable contains an object reference rather than a copy of the entire object. See [Objects and References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).